# 'NSBundle mainBundle' pathForResource strange behavior

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsbundle

I can't figure out any rhyme or reason on how `pathForResource` works... or more appropriately, doesn't.

I have a bunch of nibs in my app, they are all properly in /Build Phases/Copy Bundle Resources.

They also are properly ticked in `Target Membership` on the `File Inspector` tab.

I'm only showing 2 cases here for brevity.
When I get to the part of my code where I use `pathForResource` I get arbitrary and inconsistent results.  Even though ALL of my nibs are named ____.xib, in some cases, the only way I get a result back from `pathForResource` is if I ask for `xml` and other times I have to ask for `nib`

Anyone have an idea why this behavior is inconsistent?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These results don't seem especially surprising or inconsistent to me.

.xib files are source files for NIBs. They should not get copied *directly* into an app. They are compiled at build time to .nib files and it is those .nib files which get copied into the app. You should not expect `pathForResource:... ofType:@"xib"` to ever find a .xib file in your app. If it does, you've somehow screwed up the building of the app. The .xib file is not useful at run time.

Presumably unrelated to that, you have a file TabSale.xml that's in the Copy Bundle Resources build phase. That file *is* just copied directly. If you didn't intend to copy a raw XML file — if, for example, that's a source file that's supposed to be converted to something else at build time — then you need to figure out why it's being copied. If it's just a bogus copy of TabSale.xib for some reason, you should just get rid of it.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that about the .xib, and that's good information, but what I'm more concerned with, and didn't spell out clearly enough, is why is it that  some xibs I can ask for by specifying `xml` using `pathForResource` and other xibs I cannot.  Other xibs I HAVE TO specify `nib` in order to get back their path.  There's no apparent reason for this behavior that I can discover.

Comment: When you are specifying "xml", you are **not** getting the NIB. You are getting some other file with a similar but not identical name. Your screenshot shows this. The extension is, not surprisingly, .xml. The unexplained thing is why there's such a .xml file in your app. As I mentioned in the last paragraph of my answer, that's an issue with the project/target. Most likely, you unwittingly added .xml files to the project and to the Copy Bundle Resources build phase of your target and they're being dutifully copied in. What originally created those .xml files, I can't guess.